# Sum of int[][] rows as int[] (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to take the sum of each row in a 2d array and store the values in a new array. Right now sum[] is only returning the values stored in the first row. Please help me understand what I'm missing here.

```
public static int[] rowSum(int[][] matrix)  //find sum of digits in given row


 {


  int[] sum = new int[6];

  for (int col = 0; col < ARRAY_LENGTH; col++)
  {

     for (int row = 0; row < ARRAY_LENGTH; row++)
     {

        sum[row] += matrix[col][row];
     }


  }

  return sum;


}
```

Comment: Method returns when reaching the first occurence of `return sum;`, so `col` will never be incremented. Seems unnecessary there.

Comment: jp I removed the first return statement.

Comment: change this  sum[row] += matrix[col][row]; to  sum[col] += matrix[col][row];

Comment: sum[col] will contains the sum of each row in your array'

Comment: @raghavendra that gives the sum of the first row, but the remaining 5 digits places in rowSum[] are empty

Comment: @Dogman you mention like you want total of each row only in the new array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code works for 2D arrays of different size as well.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {
            {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, // 8 elements
            {2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 2, 86}    // 7 elements
        };
        int[] sum = rowSum(matrix);
        for (int i : sum) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static int[] rowSum(int[][] matrix) //find sum of digits in given row
    {
        int[] sum = new int[matrix.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                sum[i] = sum[i] + matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this code got it sorted. I see where I was mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Since you use Java 8 you can use:

```
return Arrays.stream(matrix) // Stream<int[]>
    .mapToInt(row -> Arrays.stream(row).sum()) // IntStream
    .toArray(); // int[]
```

Comment: Thanks this also worked, though I had not used the stream function before.

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
public static int[] rowSum(int[][] matrix)  //find sum of digits in given row


 {
  int[] sum = new int[6];
  ARRAY_LENGTH = 6;
  for (int col = 0; col < ARRAY_LENGTH; col++)
  {

     for (int row = 0; row < ARRAY_LENGTH; row++)
     {

        sum[col] += matrix[col][row];
     }
  }  
}
```

**careful with ARRAY_LENGTH**

Comment: I've declared ARRAY_LENGTH as a constant because I am limiting user input to populate the array with the same constant. I'd like to avoid switching [row][col] for readability. Not sure why you are getting downvotes though, thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't vote, but I guess it's the `return sum;` within the loop causing the method to return too soon. (which is now removed)

Comment: yes that is wrong copy pasting mistake. i just concentrated on the logic. but changed it